# DynamoDBMapper load cannot instantiate Kotlin data class

Tags: kotlin, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Using DynamoDBMapper within an AWS Lambda (i.e. not Android) written in Kotlin, I can save a record using a data class.  However when I attempt to load a record to a data class, I receive a "DynamoDBMappingException: could not instantiate class" exception.

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Test")
data class TestItem(
    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName="someKey")
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "someKey")
    var someKey: String?,

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "someValue")
    var someValue: String?
}

val ddbMapper = DynamoDBMapper(AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.defaultClient())
ddbMapper.load(TestItem::class.java, "xyz")
```

Results in the following exception:

> com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException:
>   could not instantiate class
>   com.intuit.connect_to_pro.lambda_common_core.aws_service.TestItem

With the root exception being:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   com.intuit.connect_to_pro.lambda_common_core.aws_service.TestItem.()

AWS has an example for Android that uses com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper instead of com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper. I tried the Android version, but the result was the same.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-nosql-database.html

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

The DynamoDBMapper expects a class with an empty constructor.  Using a Kotlin data class, you can specify default values for all parameters and use @JvmOverload, which will generate the empty constructor for JVM (Java).  Also all parameters need to be mutable, so you need to use "var" instead of "val".

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Test")
data class TestItem @JvmOverloads constructor(

   @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName="someKey")
   var someKey: String = "",

   var someValue: String = ""
)
```

Comment: `@JvmOverload` is not needed. In fact, it's used to generate overloads for a function, `constructor` in this case. You don't need too many constructors, just one empty one is enough. So all you need is setting default values for all parameters and use **var**.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all your classes have an empty constructor. In my case I had nested documents. Those had to have empty constructors too.

In Kotlin, an empty (parameterless) [constructor](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html) will be created if you specify default values for all the attributes.

[image]

Also, make sure that the data from the db can be converted to the data in your classes.

For example, mine failed because I had an `Integer` property  in my class while in the db I had a `String`. i.e. I had the `String` value `"30"` in the db, instead of the `Integer` value `30`.